# giving calculator input from keyboard keys without pressing calculator buttons

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I created a VB.net calculator application.It works fine but say I want to add 5+7.Then as my application works I can press 5 from the keyboard as I gave the text of button with digit 5 as `&5` but then if I press + from the keyboard it doesn't work.I have to press the `+ button` in the calculator.

I think that's because my add button is designed to handle click event as `btn_add_Click`.Is there a way I can make this application to work so that without pressing the buttons in the calculator I can press the keys in keyboard and do the computation.Here's my code:

```
Imports System.Math
Public Class Form1
    Private isFirstExist As Boolean
    Private inputOperator As String
    Private secondNum As Decimal
    Private firstNum As Decimal
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCalc.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub btn_zero_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_zero.Click
    removeFrontZero(0)

End Sub

Private Sub btn_one_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_one.Click
    removeFrontZero(1)
End Sub

Private Sub btn_two_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_two.Click
    removeFrontZero(2)
End Sub



Private Sub btn_clear_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_clear.Click
    txtCalc.Clear()
    txtCalc.Text = "0"


End Sub


'Remove zero which is at the start
Public Sub removeFrontZero(ByVal digit As Integer)
    If txtCalc.Text = "0" Then
        txtCalc.Text = CStr(digit)
    Else
        txtCalc.Text &= digit
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btn_add_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click
    inputOperator = "+"
    isFirst()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    isFirstExist = False
End Sub

Private Sub btn_equal_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_equal.Click
    If isFirstExist Then
        secondNum = CType(txtCalc.Text, Decimal)
    End If
    'Calculating the result
    Dim result As Decimal = calculate(firstNum, secondNum, inputOperator)
    txtCalc.Text = result.ToString()
    isFirstExist = False
End Sub

Private Function calculate(ByVal num1 As Decimal, ByVal num2 As Decimal, ByVal inputOp As String) As Decimal
    Dim output As Decimal
    firstNum = num1
    secondNum = num2
    Select Case inputOp
        Case "+"
            output = num1 + num2
        Case "-"
            output = num1 - num2

        Case "/"
            Dim value As Decimal
            Try
                isFirst()
                value = (num1 / num2)
            Catch ex As DivideByZeroException
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
            End Try
            output = value
        Case "*"
            output = num1 * num2
        Case "Mod"
            output = (num1 Mod num2)
        Case "^"
            output = CDec(Math.Pow(num1, num2))


    End Select
    Return output

End Function
Private Sub isFirst()
    If isFirstExist = False Then
        firstNum = CType(txtCalc.Text, Decimal)
        isFirstExist = True
        txtCalc.Text = "0"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you just do the same thing with the + button as you did with the numeric buttons (i.e., make + the keyboard accelerator)?

Comment: I did but then the addition operation doesn't get dxecuted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the textbox to hold the users input, in the Textchanged or even KeyPressed handler trap the operator keys and run the function instead of displaying the operator.

Something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtCalc.KeyPress
    If e.KeyChar = "+"c Then
        inputOperator = "+"
        isFirst()
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

To display the operator set handled to false.

Comment: Yes I am using the text box to hold user Input.Can you please explain what you mean by "in the Textchanged or even KeyPressed handler trap the operator keys and run the function instead of displaying it."

Comment: @sam_rox I added a sample for you.

Comment: Thanks.It works.I didn't know there's a event as key press.I am still a beginner to vb.net

Comment: @sam_rox - If this has answered your question, please remember to mark this answered.  Thanks.